# Starting AlertDialog after OnClick event is finished

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

On Button `ClickListener` I have some specific task to do: uninstall selected apps from the device and I want to display an `alertDialog` just after finishing the Uninstalls. I did the following but the problem is `AlertDialog` appears just at the same time when the button is clicked. I want the loop to finish first and start alert dialog. How can I do this?

```
 btnSelection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    List<AppList> stList = ((CardViewDataAdapter) mAdapter).getAppList();
                    for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
                        AppList singleApp = stList.get(i);
                        if (singleApp.isSelected() == true) {
                            String app_pkg_name = singleApp.getPackageName();
                            int UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + app_pkg_name));
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    }
                   AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Finished Uninstalling");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show AlertDialog in onActivityResult after getting result for last un-installation.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //check if Result for last uninstallation.

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Finished Uninstalling");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Override` `onActivityResult` on your `Activity`, and show dialog after receiving the result.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE){
        //  Show your dialog
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Finished Uninstalling");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```